# Hyperlink a text file in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have n excel file with a hyperlink of the text file. I want to know is there any way in excel to see the text of the file instead of hyperlink?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? It appears you are asking how to import the text from the file into your spreadsheet but it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you have a comma separated file, you can click on tab "Data" and select the button "From text". A wizard appears which will guide you through the process of importing your data into your sheet.